# Encrypt a list of logins used by a bash script -- a FIFO or...?

Tags: bash, encryption, scripting

I have a bash script which uses a text file containing a list of logins:

```
LOGINLIST=/home/user/logins.txt
while read line
do
echo $line
done < $LOGINLIST
```

I'd rather not store the list of logins as plain text, but I don't want to have to manually decrypt it every time time I run the script. (Having the script prompt for a password would be OK.)

One way I could do this would be to include a line in the script where e.g openssl decrypts the file before it gets read. Unfortunately, if the script stalled (perhaps one of the sites it's logging in to isn't responding) this would leave the file unprotected for an indeterminate period of time.

So I'd rather keep the plaintext in memory only.

This post on LinuxQuestions ( http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/can-we-hide-the-code-of-a-shell-script-370328/#post1887648 ) suggests that sending the plaintext to a FIFO might do the trick, but that's wholly unfamiliar territory for me. Is there a better / simpler way? How do I wipe the memory when the script is done?

...and is there a way to edit the encrypted login list while also keeping the plaintext in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with `openssl` and process substitution without changing the structure of your code.

To encrypt the file, use something like:

```
openssl blowfish -in plaint_text_file -out encrytped_file
```

(Choose the cipher you want, it will prompt you for a password.)

Then you can use the encrypted file with:

```
LOGINLIST=/path/to/encrypted/file
while read line
do
  echo $line
done < <(openssl blowfish -d -in $LOGINLIST)
```

This will prompt you for the password. No temporary file generated.

(Careful with the spaces in the last command, it really is `< <(`.)

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was hoping for. Is there any way to do something similar when feeding logins.txt to vi -- can I emulate the way e.g 'crontab -e' feeds vi a temporary file and then processes it after vi's done?

Answer (score 1):

You can open an existing encrypted file named encrytped_file in vim with:

```
openssl blowfish -d -in encrytped_file | vim -
```

You can create or modify/overwrite an encrypted file named encrytped_file via vim with:

```
:w !openssl blowfish -in /dev/stdin -out encrytped_file
```

Just look for the password prompts. They will get obscured a bit by vim's ui.

Here are the tricks used in this answer. You should learn them rather than copy and paste them so that you can use them in other cases.

1. vim reads from a pipe (aka: stdin or standard input) when an argument of bare hyphen is given.
2. vim can pipe its buffer to a command with `:w !command`
3. It is very common for unix commands to interpret a bare hyphen as "read from standard input" but not all commands do. In this case, you can often use `/dev/stdin`